# Simple ORM in PHP MySQL update joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, orm

I'm currently trying to write a simple ORM with PHP and mysql. I want the orm class to be able to work with joined tables. 
So here's my problem, the following code shows how I map the data the query yields into an array.

```
public function execute_query($db_connection)
{
    $query = '';

    foreach($this->sql_query as $query_part)
        $query .= $query_part;

    $result = $db_connection->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        array_push($this->m_Data, $row);
    }
}
```

db_connection is a mysqli object.
sql_query contains all the different query parts (e.g. sql_query['join'] etc.).
m_Data is the array that contains the data read from the db.

My specific problem now is when I'm using a join statement in my query this function will just override fields with the same name in my m_Data array. Also if I dont save the name's of the table the specific field data is coming from, I later can't update the tables with the same join statement.

tl,dr. I need to be able to not only save the table data like this: m_Data{ 'field_name' => 'value' } but I also need to save the table name the field is selected from. I could then save the data like this m_Data{ 'table_name.field_name' => 'value' }  which enables me later to generate a query to update the joined tables successfully.

I cant seem to find any information on how to get the origin table name for each field I pull out of the result.

If it isnt possible with mysqli I'd much appreciate it if you point me in the right direction.

extra short problem statement:
I need to get a result set and read each row seperatly. For each row I need the following information for every field selected: field_name, table_name, value.

There must be a simple answer to this but I seem to be searching for the wrong keywords to find a solution.

I hope I've written this understandable enough.

Comment: I've added an answer, but it might be useful if you'd clarify whether you intend to hold column names per table - either from a build process like Propel, or from querying the db structure in real-time.

Comment: Incidentally - I hope you are doing this just for the experience! If however you're writing a new ORM for PHP, bear in mind there are a *lot* of them out there - make sure you're not reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: Yes I'm only doing this for experience. I didnt work with php for quite some time now and I've never used it in a OO style. So I'm currently building a simple MVC framework and this ORM to dive into the matter. As I learn best by diving into a project and overcome the problems I face. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you should store table column values in an object, so if you have a related table, the column values would be stored in a separate object - and so would not interfere with the values in your primary table.

In general you might work with the ORM this way:

```
// Make joined query
$rows = ...

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    // $row just refers to the primary table
    echo $row->id;

    // You get a many:1 related table this way
    echo $row->getRelatedRow()->value;

    // You get a 1:many rows this way
    $rows = $row->getOtherRelatedRows();
}
```

Depending on how you set up your query options, getting related data may or may not initiate further SELECTs to get the required data.

Comment: That sounds good, I think I'll do that. But that still leaves my probably trivial base problem. How can I read out the three data values (table name, field name, value) for field in a row out of a result set from a mysqli object? If its not possible I'd switch to some other method no problem. I couldnt find any information on how to do this. The closest I got is reading the table name for the whole row. which wouldnt always be the same if you join two tables.

Comment: See my comment on your question about known table structure. If your ORM knows what a table looks like, it can do `SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.a FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (...)` and then grab the results as an indexed array rather than an associative one. You can then store each bit of data in the appropriate object.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me a lot. I somehow didnt think that my orm needed to know the table structure and I tried to work around that flaw. After you mentioned it a went back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_result::fetch_fields` has useful things:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

- table
- orgtable
- field type
- etc

Comment: Yes, if the OP doesn't record the table structure, he might have to do something like this. It'll be slower - although of course it could be cached in some way.

Comment: Yes this works, I've already tried it using fetch_fields but the performance isnt satisfying. So I've just made it so the ORM knows the table structures like halfer suggested. This also allows me to assign aliases to colums that enables me to select multiple colums with the same name.